# How to use the jQuery Selector in this web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to work out to select a delete icon in my own web application. [delectIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyzHS.jpg)

#### HTML

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tabs">
            <a href=""><p><span class="active">Newest</span></p></a><a href=""><p>
            <span>Oldest</span></p></a><a href=""><p><span>Add</span></p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="itemLeft">Answer emails</span>
                    <span class="itemMiddle">12-31-2016</span>
                    <span class="itemRight">1</span>
                    <b class="deleteIcon"> X </b>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="itemLeft">Prep for Monday's class</span>
                    <span class="itemMiddle">12-31-2016</span>
                    <span class="itemRight">5</span>
                    <b class="deleteIcon"> X </b>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

#### JavaScript

```
    $(".deleteIcon").on("click", function () {
    alert("Oh, clicked!");
    return false;
});
```

I failed to do so by writing it myself. So I used Chrome Web Developer Tool to find the CSS path. I tried to use the XPath(`$"[/html/body/main/div/div[2]/ul/li[ 1 ]/b]"`) and CSS Path (`$"(pathbody > main > div > div.content > ul > li:nth-child(1) > b)"`). Neither of them worked.

I tried to mark it with an ID and made only one "li" exists. The CSS selector worked all right. But when I clicked the deleteIcon`$"(#deleteIcon)"`, nothing happened.

```
#deleteIcon{

float:right;

font-weight: bold;
padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #ccc;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 5px;
font-size: 1.3em;
text-align: center;
```

}

I also tried to select my title. I found the following worked out.

```
  $(".container h1").on("click", function () {
    alert("Oh, no!");
    return false;
});
```

I do not what to do now. Can anyone help me out here?

Thank you! I would be really appreciate if you can answer my question.

## Adding more details:

I did actually add the deleteIcon into the HTML by JavaScript. I do not know whether this can have an effect on my selector.

### Actual HTML

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tabs">
            <a href=""><p><span class="active">Newest</span></p></a><a href=""><p>
            <span>Oldest</span></p></a><a href=""><p><span>Add</span></p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">



        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

### JavaScript (The important part listed below)

```
function Item(name,dueDate,type){
    this.name=name;//1
    this.dueDate=dueDate;//input2
    this.type=type;//3
};




$(".tabs a span").toArray().forEach(function (element) {
    var $element = $(element);

    // create a click handler for this element
    $element.on("click", function () {
        var $content,
            $input,
            $button,
            i;



        if ($element.parent().parent().is(":nth-child(1)")) {
            // newest first, so we have to go through
            // the array backwards

            $content = $("<ul>");
            for (i = Task.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
                // $buttondelete = $("<buttonDelete>").text("X");
                var txt1 = Task[i].toStringName();
                var txt2 = Task[i].toStringDate();
                var txt3 = Task[i].toStringType();
                //alert(txt3);
                $content.append('<li> <span class="itemLeft">'+txt1+'</span> <span class="itemMiddle">'+txt2+'</span> <span class="itemRight">'+txt3+'</span><b class="deleteIcon"> X </b>');

            }
        }



        $("main .content").append($content);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('.deleteIcon')`; the period (`.`) denotes a class-name selector, the hash (`#`) denotes an id selector.

Comment: deleteIcon is className of the element and you used it as id (#deleteIcon),  try (".deleteIcon") instead.

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a typo at the beginning. I used (".deleteIcon") all the time with the className

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating the items inside ul dynamically you should bind the click event like this :

```
$(".content").on("click", ".deleteIcon", function()
{
alert("clicked") ;
return false;
} 
) ;
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! Why is that? Could you tell me what I should Google if I want to learn more about this? Thank you again! :D

Comment: You are trying to bind an event to an object that does not exist. The way you have bound click event can work if and if you run it after ul is loaded. But you should be careful, there are other things that you must consider. The way I told is safer

Answer (score 0):

The class selector starts with a . (just like the example you say you have that works).

Try

```
$(".deleteIcon").on("click", function () {
    alert("Oh, clicked!");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. Actually I just used this class sector. I tried it again just now, it did not work.

Comment: You mean like this ? `$(".deleteIcon").click( function () {
        alert("Oh, clicked!");
        return false;
    });`