# How to generate dynamically events in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set event attributes on a group of drop-down generated dynamically but for some reason the events aren't working.
Heres's my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var idRoomTypesList = $("#idRoomTypesList").attr('value').split("_");
  for (var i = 0; i < idRoomTypesList.length; i++) {
    $("#roomTypeID-" + idRoomTypesList[i] + "_nRentedRooms").attr("onchange", generatePrice);
  }
});

var generatePrice = function () {
  alert(this.value().toString());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute be onchange?

Comment: Can you try with `"onchange"` insted of `"change"`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the unobtrusive `on()` instead of an attribute? And what is that `value()` method you're calling?

Comment: You're setting `change` to a function reference; this makes no sense.

Comment: i changed the attribute to onchange, but nothing happened

Comment: Have you tried this one? $("#selector").on('change', generatePrice);

Comment: Why not just attach them using delegated events and the `on` method. This will take care of attaching the events when the elements might not exist and using jQuery correctly for event attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this must work for you

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var idRoomTypesList = $("#idRoomTypesList").attr('value').split("_");
  for (var i = 0; i < idRoomTypesList.length; i++) {
    $("#roomTypeID-" + idRoomTypesList[i] + "_nRentedRooms").on("change", generatePrice);
  }
});    
    var generatePrice = function () {
      alert($(this).val());
    }
```

And have a look at this:
 [How to use the jQuery Selector in this web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859913/how-to-use-the-jquery-selector-in-this-web-application/33860115#33860115)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select class="dynamicSelects">
 ....
</select>
```

JS:

```
var generatePrice = function () {
  alert(this.value);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('change', '.dynamicSelects', generatePrice);
});
```

This is an example of using the `on` method provided by jQuery and delegating the events. This means that even if those drop downs are not in the DOM yet you can still attach the event to it and whenever they exist in the DOM the event will fire. It basically says attach these events to body but fire on elements with the class `dynamicSelects`. This covers adding any other dynamically generated drop downs with this class later as well.

Setting attributes to attach events, while it may work, should really be done using the `on` method or in plain JS the `addEventListener`, in my opinion.

Also when operating on plain DOM elements the value property is not a function so no `value()` is needed. Just `this.value`. And you don't need to convert it to a string because value returns a string. If it were a jquery object then you can do `$(this).val()` which is a function.

I only suggest this change of course because if you are going to use a library like jQuery at least take advantage of the things it offers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you search into the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/)?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $idRoomTypesList = $("#idRoomTypesList").attr('value').split("_");
  for (var i = 0; i < idRoomTypesList.length; i++) {
    $("#roomTypeID-" + idRoomTypesList[i] + "_nRentedRooms").attr("onchange", generatePrice);
  }

    $( "#idRoomTypesList" ).change(generatePrice());

});

var generatePrice = function () {
  alert(this.value().toString());
}
```